# How to create different views for mui DataGrid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, react-typescript

For my DataGrid, I would like to show it in the form of a gallery and the form of a chart sometimes.
Just like in https://www.notion.so views

[image]

- I tried this

```
function DataGridView(props: any) {
   const VISIBLE_FIELDS = [props.children[0].data[0].Table.columns.map((c: any) => c.field)];

   const {data, setFilterModel} = useDemoData({
       dataSet: 'Employee',
       visibleFields: VISIBLE_FIELDS,
       rowLength: 100,
   });

   let views = [
       {id: 'dlkjfoi23', name: "table", component: <PaymentContract {...props} />},
       {id: 'lksdjifow', name: "galary", component: <GalleryView items={props.children[0].data[0].Table.rows}/>}
   ];

   const {OptionsComponent, ViewsComponent} = useViews({views, default: 'xxx'})



   const handleCustomFilter = React.useCallback(
       (value: string) => {
           setFilterModel((prevFilterModel) => ({
               ...prevFilterModel,
               items: [
                   {
                       columnField: 'name', 
                       operatorValue: 'contains',
                       value,
                   },
               ],
           }));
       },
       [setFilterModel],
   );

   return <Box
       sx={{
           width: '100%',
       }}
       contentEditable={false}
   >
       <Box
           sx={{
               borderBottom: 1, borderColor: 'divider',
               // opacity: isOver ? 1 : 0, transition: '0.3s',
               // position:"absolute",
           }}
       >
           {OptionsComponent}
           <TextField
               label="Custom Search"
               variant="outlined"
               onChange={(e) => handleCustomFilter(e.target.value)}
               size="small" // Set the size to "small" to make the input thinner
           />
       </Box>

       {ViewsComponent}

   </Box>
}
```

but I need to do it in a more native way. in which I but the `OptionsComponent` inside a

```
slots={{
toolbar: OptionsComponent
```

- Description:
  in this component, I have a dropdown in which when U selects **gallery** I will render the data in the form of a gallery, and when U selects, **"table"**, the data will be rendered in the form of a table. But, I want the same functionality without using the component in this way. I want

1. put the options inside slots.toobar
2. Use cells render or columns custom render or rows custom rendering, or anything like this.